# polygon not defined on board in Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I am trying to create a polygon in my pcb in altium. At first I thought it didn't create a polygon at all, but now I realized it is creating it, but only outside of the board. The polygon inside of the board does not exist. I tried to define a keep out layer to circumvent this, but it did not work. Any ideas?

Thank you

[image: polygon outline]

[image: polygon outline]

Comment: Is this the only polygon in the design?

Comment: as of then it was. I created a polygon that defined the board before, and it did not pour. I would get a catastrophic failure when trying to pour. I then editted preferences so that it repours whenever I edit it, and it looks like it's doing that..

Comment: Looks like you may have defined a polygon pour cutout around the entire board.